# A request was made to load the default HttpClient provider but one could not be found on the classpath

Tags: azure, apache-spark, azure-databricks

I'm trying to remove some blobs from Azure storage blob using azure-storage-blob lib, my app is deployed in databricks as a spark job. In addition, my code worked correctly on my local machine

I have the error bellow :

```
IllegalStateException: A request was made to load the default HttpClient provider but one could not be found on the classpath. If you are using a dependency manager, consider including a dependency on azure-core-http-netty or azure-core-http-okhttp. Depending on your existing dependencies, you have the choice of Netty or OkHttp implementations. Additionally, refer to https://aka.ms/azsdk/java/docs/custom-httpclient to learn about writing your own implementation
```

My code :

```html
 val accountName: String = spark.conf.get("AZURE_BLOB_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME")
    val accountKey: String =  spark.conf.get(s"fs.azure.account.key.$accountName.blob.core.windows.net")
    val endpoint = "https://" + accountName + ".blob.core.windows.net"

    val credential = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(accountName, accountKey)
    val client = new BlobServiceClientBuilder().endpoint(endpoint).credential(credential).buildClient
    val containerClient = client.getBlobContainerClient(containerName)

    containerClient
      .listBlobsByHierarchy(s"$folderName/")
      .forEach(blob =>
        containerClient
          .getBlobClient(blob.getName)
          .deleteIfExists()
      )
```

Any idea to resolve this problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You probably have following merge strategy configured in `build.sbt`:

```
case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
```

Please check if `META-INF/services` directory is available in your jar.